# Can I delete the files in C:\users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android\

Tags: android

Can I delete the files in C:\users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android ?  It's eatin up almost 70GB of disk space.

Comment: why *wouldn't* you be able to remove files from your computer?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Go to SDK Manager and uninstall some of the build_tools or obsolete versions of android.

Comment: I thought one wasn't supposed to delete files under C:\users\my_user\AppData

Comment: I uninstalled all SDKs less than API15 and it didn't free up any space in C:\users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android

Comment: try deleting your Gradle cache directory @ USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/build-cache-1

Answer (score 5):

Well, the Android SDK is in there, including in all your package content (and backwards compatibility).

If you are concerned about space, remove some packages (Like Android N, Watch, TV, or others you may not use).

If you are really paranoid about extra files, uninstall everything and re-install a fresh android SDK and only take that which you need.

Comment: I uninstalled all SDKs less than API15 and it didn't clear up any data in C:\users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android

Comment: Eclipse references the Android SDK in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android, so I will relocate the other three AppData\Local\Android sdk folders off line and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used Google Andoid SDK in a year.  I uninstalled it, then deleted the AppData\Android folder to free up 262GB.  I can always reinstall the SDK later when I need it again.